# A question concerning positive definite matrix functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, integration, matrix-analysis

Let $C(e^{i\theta})$ be an $m\times n$ ($m\ge n$) matrix-valued continuous function of $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$. Let $A_1(e^{i\theta})$ and $A_2(e^{i\theta})$ be two $n\times n$ *positive definite* matrix-valued continuous function of $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$ (i.e. $A_1(e^{i\theta}),\,A_2(e^{i\theta})>0$, $\forall\,\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$) satisfying $A_1(e^{i\theta})\neq A_2(e^{i\theta})$. Suppose that it holds
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} C(e^{i\theta})A_1(e^{i\theta})C^*(e^{i\theta})\,\mathrm{d}\theta\neq \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} C(e^{i\theta})A_2(e^{i\theta})C^*(e^{i\theta})\,\mathrm{d}\theta,
$$
where the superscript $*$ denotes the Hermitian transpose.

> **My Question:** Let $P(e^{i\theta})$ be any *positive definite* $n\times n$ continuous function of $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$, does \eqref{1} imply that
>   $$\tag{2}\label{2}
> \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} CA_1^{1/2}P A_1^{1/2}C^*\,\mathrm{d}\theta\neq \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} CA_2^{1/2}P A_2^{1/2}C^*\,\mathrm{d}\theta\ \  \text{?}
> $$

**N.B.** In Eq. \eqref{2} I omitted the dependence on $\theta$ for readability. Moreover, the superscript ${1/2}$ denotes the principal matrix square root.

**Note.** The answer is negative, as a counterexample posted in a comment by Pietro Majer shows. However, it is not still clear if the answer is negative if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are taken of the form
$$
A_1(e^{i\theta})=(C^*(e^{i\theta}) X_1 C(e^{i\theta}))^{-1},\quad A_2(e^{i\theta})=(C^*(e^{i\theta}) X_2 C(e^{i\theta}))^{-1}
$$
where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are constant $n\times n$ positive matrices and $C$ is of full column rank a.e..

Comment: I think it does not, in general. Take e.g. $C=I$, and $A_1>0$ and $A_2>0$ two diagonal matrices, such that (1) holds, and each element in the diagonal of $A_1-A_2$ changes sign. Then there exists a diagonal matrix $P(\theta)>0$ such that $P(A_1-A_2)$ has zero mean, so in (2) there is equality.

Comment: @PietroMajer: I completely agree, thanks! Actually in my problem $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not general but they have a particular form, namely (assuming that $C$ is of full column rank a.e. and omitting the dependence on $\theta$) $A_1=(C^*X_1 C)^{-1}$ and $A_2=(C^*X_2 C)^{-1}$ with $X_1$, $X_2>0$ *constant* positive definite matrices. I thought however that the more general result I described in this question could have been true, but this is not the case as you correctly observed.

Comment: I wonder whether you have some further insights w.r.t. the particular case which I just described above. (Indeed, it seems to me that your counterexample does not work in this case).